# How to install a custom diagnostic data adapter for use in Microsoft Test Manager?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I'm using Microsoft Test Manager to do some automated testing using lab environments. I'd like to take advantage of choosing a data adapter in the test settings, so I created my own going off of the MSDN documentation: [How to: Create a Diagnostic Data Adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286737.aspx)

MSDN says to copy the resulting built files to the target machine as described here: [How to: Install a Custom Diagnostic Data Adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286708.aspx). I did this; however, the directory they specified didn't exist, so I created it with the same name.

The directory I copied my files to was:

> Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\DataCollectors

Now, I did this on both my local machine and my target machine, yet Microsoft Test Manager doesn't recognize its existence in the "test settings". Is it just supposed to automatically appear? Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't provide much detail.

I'm wondering if the reason MTM doesn't recognize the data adapter is because the directory "PrivateAssemblies\DataCollectors" didn't exist previously before I created it.

Has anyone been able to create a data adapter and get it working and recognized in MTM?

Comment: Can you find any of the MS created data adapters on disk?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using custom *data adapter* and all I had to do to install it was to copy the dll into the folder mentioned by MSDN.

Can you see other *data adapters* (shipped with MTM) in *Test Settings*?

[image]

The dlls for these *data adapters* are also located in the directory you are missing on your machine.

If you can see these *data adapters* then try to find following dll on your machine:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.EventLog.dll
```

Just in case they have been installed in another folder for any reason.

Comment: Do you need Visual Studio Enterprise to create your custom data adapter?

Comment: No, the customer _DDA_ is just a dll you created.
You need _VS Enterprise_ or _VS Test Professional_ if you want to use _Microsoft Test Manage_r or Test Hub in TFS Web access.

Comment: So does it mean that I can create my custom data collector by implementing abstract `DataCollector` and put the result of compilation in `\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\DataCollectors` in order to get it work? Because I use VS Professional. I use all steps mentioned above, I saw my collector in `.testsettings` file, but I got an error during loading my data collector assembly. It was not found. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: In general, you don't need any special licence for executing your tests. My tests are running on virtual machines and the only piece of MS software installed is the *TestAgent* which does not require any licences.
So I'm pretty sure your issue is not license related.

I've nerve used it this way, unfortunately. I set my custom DDAs using MTM (*Microsoft Test Manager*) since I have the licenses required. So I don't have any experience in setting it up via .testsettings file. I'm sorry :(